# How to recode values in geospacial data frame by conditioning on surrounding values?

Tags: r, geospatial, distance

I have a data frame that looks similar to this:

```
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  region = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 60, replace = TRUE),
  year   = sample(c(2001:2023), 60, replace = TRUE),
  Type   = sample(c("Forrest", "Cropland", "Water"), 60, replace = TRUE),
  x      = rnorm(60, mean = 40, sd = 3)
  y      = rnorm(60, mean = 43, sd = 5)
)
```

The data derives from geospacial raster files.
What I am trying to do is to get the points that are neighbouring (orthogonally and diagonally) a point that is coded with `"Cropland"` in the `Type` column, but that are not coded with `"Cropland"` themselves. I want the data to be seperately grouped by `region`and `year`.

As this has to be translated into the logic of a data frame, I wanted to do this with finding the eight "neighbouring" rows in the data frame for each rows. As the distances is not equally distributed (there is a slight variation in the distances between the points in the x- and y-axes), I wanted to find these eight points by searching for the minimum distance from one point in all of the eight directions.

So, my aim is to get a data frame like this:

```
df_solved <- data.frame(
  region = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  year   = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2023),
  share_cropland = c(0.012, 0.341, 0.0012, 0.0213, 0.212, 0.123, 0.152, 0.0012, 0.046)
)
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!